# Efficient way to query database with multiple conditions in laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder, multiple-conditions

Is it possible to make this a single query?

```
$yl_min = DB::connection($this->db2)->table('historical')
    ->where([['slug','=',$crypto_id],['low_usd','!=', null]])
    ->whereBetween('created_time',[$this->range_1y,$this->hislatest])
    ->min('low_usd');

$yl = DB::connection($this->db2)->table('historical')
    ->select('id','coin','low_usd','created_time','created_at')
    ->where([['slug','=',$crypto_id],['low_usd',$yl_min]])
    ->whereBetween('created_time',[$this->range_1y,$this->hislatest])
    ->first();
```

I've tried this but no luck:

```
$yl = DB::connection($this->db2)->table('historical')
    ->select('id','coin','created_time','created_at',DB::raw('SELECT MIN(low_usd) as low_usd'))
    ->where([['slug','=',$crypto_id],['low_usd','!=', null]])
    ->whereBetween('created_time',[$this->range_1y,$this->hislatest])
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your query code, I found the two query condition is same, and you just want to get min `low_usd` record,

I think you can just use the multiple condition and `ORDER BY low_usd ASC`, then take the first one:

```php
$yl = DB::connection($this->db2)->table('historical')
                ->where([['slug','=',$crypto_id],['low_usd','!=', null]])
                ->whereBetween('created_time',[$this->range_1y,$this->hislatest])
                ->orderBy('low_usd','asc')
                ->select('id','coin','low_usd','created_time','created_at')
                ->first();
```

After this, if you want to make this query more efficient,

you need to **add index on `slug`, `low_usd`, `created_time`**

Comment: Thanks, it works but need to add "asc" in orderBy. Indexing works wonders. I think I was really focused on using the MIN function. Do you think there's a way you can achieve the same result using the MIN function? Anyway, I'll accept your answer above.

Comment: @user10971804 honestly `orderBy('low_usd')` will order by default `ASC`  if I don't pass the second parameter. And if you want to use MIN function and one query, you  can still do it like `subquery` or `select MIN(low_usd) from ... group by slug `

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. But in MySql,  'asc' order is not default. I guess it's just right to have a default order cause there no use-case I know if it's not in order.